# Interpretation of "what is the probability of having offspring that are male with blue eyes"?

Tags: meaning

I'm not sure if this is asking for:
The probability of your child being both male and blue eyed?
or
The probability of your male child having blue eyes? (If you have a male child)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about [conditional probability](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/condprob.htm).

Comment: In statistical probability this means "if mating produces offspring,  what would be the probability of the offspring being both male and having blue eyes. Nothing is mentioned about human children in the quotation.

Comment: @Laurel: isn't it a question about the meaning of an English sentence? I don't see how it's asking about probability.

Comment: @user209797: It's the first. If it was the second, it would be something like "Among male offspring, what is the probability of having blue eyes".

Answer (score 2):

It's your first option, and this is indicated by "with" joining both "male" and "blue eyes" as a single condition. If they wanted to know the odds of your male child having blue eyes, they would have phrased it as "What is the probability of male offspring having blue eyes?"